# Excel. date and time = workshift X

Tags: excel, datetime, if-statement, vlookup, weekday

I have a cell with date and time in the format: (dd-mm-yyyy tt:mm)
Based on this i'd like to extract the shift that made the data in my excel file.

Shift times are as follows

- Dayshift: 06:01-14:00 (Monday-Thursday) 06:00-13:20(Friday)
- Eveningshift: 14:01-22:50 (Monday-Thursday)
- Nightshift: 22:36-06:00 (Sunday evening - Monday morning) 22:51-06:00 (Monday-Friday)
- Weekendshift: 13:21-01:20 (Friday) 10:40-22:35 (Sunday)
- Any event outside those shift should be returned as shift: Overtime

  I've been @ this for hours with no result. Anyone up for the challenge? :)

Comment: Show what you have tried, and what you expect for a result given an input.

Comment: Well, my solution is to have the workshifts times listed in the sheet and the reference to that, like this:
=SUM.HVISER(Data!$BD:$BD;Data!$BC:$BC;">="&TEKST(B22;"dd-mm-åååå")&" "&TEKST(B21;"tt:mm");Data!$BC:$BC;"<="&TEKST(B25;"dd-mm-åååå")&" "&TEKST(B24;"tt:mm");Data!$O:$O;"="&$G$3)

What i would love is a formula where i from a cell containing dd-mm-yyyy tt:mm have a cell tell me the shift that made that data entry.

Comment: Do you see how hard your formula is to read the way it is formatted in your comments?  Pleae edit your question to add both the formula, and and example of your input and desired output.

Comment: Do not add details in comments. Instead, [edit] your post to include it there where it can be seen. The code you dumped in the comment is unreadable; if you put it in the question itself where it can be formatted and is easily seen, it's usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way to do this is to set up a table with columns for the various parameters, and a calculated column for the weekday.

*I Named the table `Shifts` and am using structured references for ease of maintenance and future understanding, but you could use regular references if you must.*

**Shift Table**

[image]

Formula in E2:

```
=MATCH([@Day],{"Sunday";"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday"},0)
```

A formula that will return the Shift, given a timestamp:

```
=IFERROR(
       LOOKUP(2,1/(
              (MOD(timeStamp,1)>=Shifts[startTime])*
              (MOD(timeStamp,1)<=Shifts[endTime])*
              (WEEKDAY(timeStamp)=Shifts[wdNum])),Shifts[Shift]),
      "Overtime")
```

**random results**

*using formula in a Table with structured references*

```
=IFERROR(
       LOOKUP(2,1/(
              (MOD([@timeStamp],1)>=Shifts[startTime])*
              (MOD([@timeStamp],1)<=Shifts[endTime])*
              (WEEKDAY([@timeStamp])=Shifts[wdNum])),Shifts[Shift]),
      "Overtime")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping out Ron. Really appreciate it!